# Dynamically changing a Javascript map statement

Tags: javascript, dictionary, eval

I want to evaluate a dynamically created string inside a map function.
This is how it should work:

```
ar arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = arr.map(v=>((v+5)*6));     //Gives  [36, 42, 48, 54, 60]
```

I have created a string as below:

```
var s = '((v+5)*6)';
var arr2 = arr.map(v=>eval(s));      // I need something like this to work!
```

Can you do two things please?

1. Show how this can be done using eval on the string I have created (or an amended string).
2. Suggest another (better) method of doing this - I'm sure there is one.
3. Don't just skip out point 1)

Thanks

Comment: why not take a function istead of a astring?

Comment: Could you add some more context as to why `eval` is necessary?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use eval? Even if you’re relying on user input that’s never a good idea.

Comment: The map statement is dynamically created. So the input could be something like this:
var cmds = [ [ [ '+', '5' ], [ '*', '6' ] ] ];
I can code the input to form any string. I chose to try a method which took the array above and produces the string: "((v+5)*6))".

Comment: Point1: Your `eval` solution still works. Point2: You should provide more context to get help.

Comment: I get this error when I try and run the eval code in my question: 
TypeError: eval is not a function

Answer (score 3):

Notwithstanding the fact that `eval` probably is the wrong way to implement, this would be the way to make it run.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let s = '((v+5)*6)';
const arr2 = arr.map(eval(`v => ${s}`));
console.log(arr2);
```

Otherwise you should use or create a parser for the string, like [Math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html). Or check [this page](https://medium.com/@stoopidguy1992/how-to-write-a-math-expression-parser-in-javascript-b5147bc9466b) for ideas.

Comment: I made a booboo. Eval is disabled in the environment I am using. 
So my code would have worked - explains why I was so confused.
Thanks for your help and all others who contributed. 
I will look at one of the other methods you suggested.

Comment: ;) I'd say it is disabled for a reason. Hope the links in my answer can help then.

Comment: I can't use the math library. 
Is there no easier way to do this than to write my own maths expression parser?

Comment: The order of operations should follow the brackets I have added from inner to outer.

Answer (score 0):

arr.map(v=>calc(v))

Pass something like this to the map function:

```
function calc(v){
          if (a=='plus') {return v+n;}
          if (a=='minus') {return v-n;}
          if (a=='multiply') {return v*n;}
          if (a=='divide') {return v/n;}
          if (a=='modulo') {return v%n;}
 }
```